# Odds of turning all the columns in solitaire without drawing from the pack

Tags: probability

Windows solitaire experiment.
Start a game and see how many cards can be exposed in the columns before a draw from the pack is needed.
(Single or three card game makes no difference here)
As a time killing exercise I have been doing this as I noticed you could often turn quite a large number when starting a game. It became a "game in itself" to keep restarting and seeing how many I could turn without going to the pack. After a couple of years I got a "one left" but it has taken 23 years (first on a commodore 64) to start a game and turn all the column cards without drawing one from the pack.
What are the odds (other than pretty long!) 
(For the curious I will say nothing magical happens when you achieve this rare state of play but it does guarantee you have a winning game :)